# PHP format email message

Tags: php, string, email

In the input `<textarea>` text looks good 3 lines

```
First Line 
John Smith
Ivan Normand
```

when i capture input with php and send email text looks like this
when i capture input with php and send email text looks like this

```
First Line                    Bellman:\r\n                          \r\nJohn Smith\r\nIvan Normand
```

I use Thunderbird to receive email and i see this mess. It shows properly in webmail.

```
$message = $_POST["message"];

$headers = "From: $from";

// boundary

$semi_rand = md5(time());

$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

// headers for attachment

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

// multipart boundary

$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

// preparing attachments

for ($x = 0; $x < count($files); $x++) {

    $file = fopen($files[$x], "rb");

    $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$x]));

    fclose($file);

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .

        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$names[$x]\"\n" .

        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";

    if ($x == count($files) - 1) {
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\r\n";
    } else {
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }
}

// send

$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Is there any chance of seeing the code that generates the email text?

Comment: i think the email body is escaped incorrectly

Comment: but why not use http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/ all functionality you need is done already :)

Comment: Because i am not looking for easy ways.  :)

Comment: if you will invent the wheel while people around you are riding bikes already :)) then i dont know how fast you will finish your project :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br) of php, which convert '\n' character to '
'.

You can use it like below:

```
$message = nl2br($_POST["message"]); //Please take care of sql injection here
```